# Solution of nonhomogenious differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Kindly help me regarding below math problem.
How can I prove?

> Show that if $y_1(x)$ is a solution of
>   $$y'' + ay' + by = f_1(x)$$
>   and if $y_2(x)$ is a solution of
>   $$y'' + ay' + by = f_2(x)$$
>   then the function $y_1(x) + y_2(x)$ is a solution of
>   $$y'' + ay' + by = f_1(x) + f_2(x).$$

Comment: Plug $y_1+y_2$ in the equation and conclude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

> $$y(x)=y_1(x)+y_2(x) \implies y'=y'_1+y'_2 \implies y''=y''_1+y''_2 $$

then substitute in the ode

> $$ y'' + ay' + by = f_1(x) + f_2(x) $$

and regroup the functions $y_1, y_2$ and use the facts that $y_1$ and $y_2$ satisfies the equations

> $$ y_1'' + ay_1' + by_1 = f_1(x)  $$
>
> $$ y_2'' + ay_2' + by_2 = f_2(x)  $$

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick help....May God bless you...

Comment: @PankajKumarSharma: You are very welcome! Do you know how to accept answers?

Comment: @PankajKumarSharma: I believe there is a green icon or something like this you need to click on it

Comment: Yes I did Sir...

Comment: @PankajKumarSharma: Thank you!

Comment: If I want to give you some point for your answers for best explanations.. Can I do that?

Comment: @PankajKumarSharma: You can upvote the answer! Thanks anyway!